# Why does the GUI root password work, but su doesn't?

Tags: permissions, sudo, password

I need to install Wacom drivers on my work laptop, which involves running `make`. My account was set up with some sudo permissions (I can run `apt-get` and a few other commands), but not `make`.

In case I needed more permissions, I was also provided with the admin password which is needed, for example, for connecting to new WiFi networks and is entered through the GUI. Presumably this is also the root password for my laptop?

However, I cannot seem to run programs as root with this password:

```
xyz@laptop:~$ su
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

and using my own login,

```
xyz@laptop:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for xyz: 
Sorry, user xyz is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as root on laptop.
```

I also do not have read permissions for `etc/sudoers`. Do I have a way to run `make`?

Comment: Solved? I seem to be able to use pkexec su. Still unsure why it doesn't work without this - is the GUI password different from the root password?

Comment: When you authenticate using pkexec or the polkit GUI, which user does it ask you authenticate as? The rules set for polkit can be different from that of sudo, so they can let you do different things with both.

Comment: Password is the same. Only the configuration what you are allowed to run via sudo and via GUI (polkit/pkexec) are different. The message from your attempt to run `sudo -i` does not say incorrect password; it says you are not authorized to run `/bin/bash` as root. It means the password itself was correct. It is also not a root password. Both sudo and pkexec require to enter your own account password, ie. the same password you use to login to your account (but it is possible that your system is set up so that you don't need that password to login)

Comment: @muru this solved it for me. Confusingly, the account has been named "administrator" (this is probably very natural, but it meant that the polkit GUI prompt was headed with "administrator" - to me this didn't immediately jump out as a username.)

Answer (score 1):

```
xyz@laptop:~$ su
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

Is the way root enabled systems work. Like redhat, or SUSE. The equivalent  on systems using (like Ubuntu) would be...

```
$ sudo su
```

`sudo -i` works too for admin accounts.

Comment: `sudo su` is nonsense ;-)

Comment: technically it is the equivalent of `su` :D It leads to a `#` :)

Comment: `sudo -s` or `sudo -i` makes sense on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Pilot6: `sudo su` is not a nonsense. When typing just `su`, you must enter the **root** password. When typing `sudo su` (assuming you are allowed to do that), you must enter **your own** password. So if you want to give someone root access without giving them actual root account password, `sudo su` is the way to do it. Also, if the root account is disabled (as it is generally on Ubuntu), `su` won't work, while `sudo su` works.

Comment: @raj naah pilot6 is correct ;) sudo su should not exist. It was probably added to stop those `su` users from complaining :D I favor `sudo -i ` myself.